# Infinitesimal interval in the limits of integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have always understood that $df(x)=f(x+dx)-f(x)$, which is the definition of the "$d$" prefix, regardless of where the variable $x$ stands in the function. This leads me to the following regarding the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt)=f(x)$$
Based on my understanding of the "$d$" prefix, I am able to prove this by the following reasoning for the **numerator** of the above equation.
$$d\bigg(\int_a^xf(t)dt \bigg) = \int_a^{x+dx}f(t)dt - \int_a^{x}f(t)dt= \int_x^{x+dx}f(t)dt=f(x)dx$$
However, I am told that having a $dx$ within the limits of an integral does not make sense, despite it giving the desired result.

But isn't this what the differential "$d$" stands for? How is this reasoning then incorrect?

Comment: You are fine, since your integration variable is $t$. If you really want to be exact, use the limit definition of the derivative.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for verifying. Is it actually possible to correspond a Riemann summation for such an integral?
$$\int_x^{x+dx}f(t)dt$$
I'd assume this corresponds to 1 step of a Riemann summation of $f(t_k)$ where $t_1=x$, thus
$$\lim_{max \Delta t_k \to 0} \sum_{k=1}^1 f(t_k^*) \Delta t_k =\lim_{max \Delta t_k \to 0}f(x)\Delta t$$
But I don't see how the $\Delta t$ should transform into $\Delta x$. Any idea?

Comment: Differentials are not just "small values". $dx$ is a different beast than $\Delta x$. Berkley castigated them as being "the ghosts of departed quantities". In modern standard mathematics, differentials are considered a notational convention only, not actual mathematical objects. There are ways to interpret them as actual mathematical objects, but they involve extensions to the real number system, which you would then have to also define integration over. This is why someone told you it didn't make sense to have $x + dx$ in the limit.

Comment: How do you justify $\int_x^{x+dx} f(t)\,dt = f(x) dx$? That effectively is what you are trying to prove, and you just assert it is so.

Comment: @PaulSinclair How would otherwise the notation.. $$d\bigg(\int_a^xf(t)dt \bigg)$$ ..be written out exactlyt?

Comment: You tell me. You are the one who wrote it down as a proof, not me. If you don't know what it means, then you haven't proved anything.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I already mentioned in my OP that it's the difference between a function with variable $x+dx$ minus said function with variable $x$.  And since the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that $$\frac{d\bigg(\int_a^xf(t)dt \bigg)}{dx}=f(x)dx$$ then I'd reason the numerator is equal to that definition. Hence me asking you now how you'd otherwise write out the $d$ prefix for an integration.

Comment: You are claiming to prove the FTC from it, so you cannot use the FTC to define it. (Actually, this is the *first* FTC, a.k.a, the "differentiation theorem" - when people just say "the FTC", they are referring to the *second* FTC - that $\int_a^bf'(x)\,dx = f(a) - f(b)$ when $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Perhaps "prove" is a poor choice of wording form my side. A better word would be reasoning that $f(x)dx$ is equal to $\int_x^{x+dx}f(t)dt$. If it's incorrect then I'd like to understand what the $d$ prefix would look like written out for an integration with $x$ as the upper limit, since it is used in FTC.

Comment: As an intuition, This is fine. I've seen it done many times exactly as you've written it. But understand it is only an intuition, because the very objects you are manipulating - differentials - are ill-defined. They are excellent for guiding you to true results, and good methods for proving those results, but they themselves do not constitute a proof. For that you need to back off to deltas, and pay close attention that everything you want to go to zero with the deltas actually does.

Comment: Concerning your Riemann sum, on $[x, x + \Delta x]$ there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) - \epsilon < f(t) < f(x) + \epsilon$. Further, because $f$ is continuous, for any such $\epsilon$, you can choose a $\Delta x$ small enough to make the inequality hold. Since the $t_k$ partition $[x, x+\Delta x]$, $\sum_k \Delta t_k = \Delta x$ and therefore the Riemann sum is between $(f(x) - \epsilon)\Delta x$ and $(f(x) + \epsilon)\Delta x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you. I have one last question. For this equation..
$$f(E)dE=\int_v^{v+z}g(t)dt$$
I'd like to solve for $z$. I deduced $$f(E)dE=g(k)z$$ Where $k$ is some value between $v$ and $v+z$. Since $z$ is deduced from $dE$, then $z$ is also infinitesimal such that $g(k)=g(v)$. Also, $v$ must depend on $E$ according to the equation, thus $v=v(E)$. Solving for $z$ gives
$$z=\frac{f(E)dE}{g(v(E))}$$
I know that $z$ must be $dv$ but is there any way to prove this? Using the chain rule didn't help and I am out of ideas. 

Is this actually possible using this specific approach?

Comment: $dz$ is the infinitesimal change in $v$ that corresponds to the infinitesimal change $dE$ in $E$. Which is also the definition of $dv$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Is there any way to show this algebraically from my approach? Or would this approach always lead to a more general definition of dv?

Comment: Applying the definition of a symbol is "algebraic". There is no "more general definition of $dv$". When you have inter-related variables such as $E$ and $v$, and you make an infinitesimal change to the system, $dE$ and $dv$ are the notations for the corresponding changes in each variable. By setting up the problem as you did, you required $z$ to be $dv$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ok got it. Sorry I have one final question just to make sure. Since the integrand's variable takes on the values of the integration limits, does that mean that for $$\int_E^{E+dE}f(t)dt=f(E)dE$$
The integrand's $dt$ essentially becomes the value $dE$?